# DisplayObject.rotation not matching trig functions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

I'm trying to label an animated pie chart, and I've been having a great deal of trouble getting rotated objects to line up with trigonometrically-positioned objects. So, for example, if I have a pie piece that's middle is angle theta and has been rotated n degrees in a tween, and then I try to position a label with code like this:

```
label.x = center.x + Math.cos((theta + n)/180 * Math.PI) * radius;
label.y = center.y + Math.sin((theta + n)/180 * Math.PI) * radius;
```

the label is often not aligned with the center of the pie slice. Since I am also zooming in to the pie chart a great deal, the error becomes significant enough that it occasionally causes the label to miss the pie slice altogether. The error seems relatively unpredictable, and it looks a great deal like a rounding error, but I don't see any obvious rounding going on (the trig functions evaluate to ten or so decimal places, which should be more than enough here).

How can I get these labels to position correctly?

Comment: As a note: just shifting the labels around using rotation doesn't work well either, because I hit the problem again when I then try to write an algorithm to prevent labels from overlapping. Argh!

Comment: theta + n is the rotation of the pie piece around the center of the pie chart?

Comment: theta is the midsection of the pie piece. (So if the first piece represented 25%, it's theta would be 45 degrees, and if the second piece then represented 50%, its theta would be 180 degrees.) The whole  pie then gets rotated by an animation, by n degrees.

Comment: rx = xcos@ - ysin@
ry = xsin@ + ycos@

If you're rotation from (0,1) then:
rx = -sin@
ry = cos@

so then instead of cos for x and sin for y above you should use -sin for x and cos for y.

If it works I'll post it as a solution LOL

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. The labels ended up rotated about 90 degrees from where they were supposed to go.

Comment: lol I was doing counterclockwise for somereason. x' = xcosθ + ysinθ and y' = − xsinθ + ycosθ. so try sin@, cos@.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem. I'm rotating from (1, 0), not from (0,1).

Comment: Also I think it's angle * pie / 180.

Answer (score 0):

rx = xcos@ + ysin@

ry = -xsin@ + ycos@

If you're rotating from (0,1) then:

rx = sin@

ry = cos@

So then instead of cos for x and sin for y above you should use sin for x and cos for y.

```
label.x = center.x + Math.sin((theta + n) * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
label.y = center.y + Math.cos((theta + n) * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
```

Comment: All this talk of 'Math.PIE' is making me hungry :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, my math is correct. I am, at least, using the correct trigonometric functions.